# How do I properly display checkbox values on Laravel edit blade?

Tags: php, laravel

Facing an annoying issue with checkboxes in a form I have created in Laravel.

I have assigned a value to each checkbox and when submitting to the database implode all the values together into an array.

The data will submit successfully to the database, but when I try to edit a submission, only the text based data shows up while the checkboxes will not re-populate.

[Click here to see a preview of the issue.](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1MgfQyyrsFDU9-buXmzXxeiuKSZ7bxEFo6qZkYRN7M6w/edit?usp=sharing)

I have tried a ton of this from StackoverFlow to to avail so wondering if anyone has an idea?

Happy to share code sample below

**Complete Edit Blade**

```
<x-app-layout>
  <x-slot name="header">
    <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight"> Edit Assessment </h2>
  </x-slot>
  <div>
    <div class="max-w-4xl mx-auto py-10 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div class="mt-5 md:mt-0 md:col-span-2">
        <form method="post" action="{{ route('assessments.update', $assessment->id) }}"> @csrf @method('PUT') <div class="shadow overflow-hidden sm:rounded-md">
            <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white sm:p-6">
              <label for="learner" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Learner</label>
              <input type="text" name="learner" id="learner" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full" value="{{ old('learner',  $assessment->learner) }}" /> @error('learner') <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white sm:p-6">
              <label for="type" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Type</label>
              <input type="text" name="type" id="type" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full" value="{{ old('type', $assessment->type) }}" /> @error('type') <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white sm:p-6">
              <label for="assessor" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Assessor</label>
              <input type="text" name="assessor" id="assessor" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full" value="{{ old('assessor', $assessment->assessor) }}" /> @error('assessor') <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white sm:p-6">
              <label for="inquiry" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Inquiry</label>
              <input type="text" name="inquiry" id="inquiry" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full" value="{{ old('inquiry', $assessment->inquiry) }}" /> @error('inquiry') <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white sm:p-6">
              <label for="competency" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Competency</label>
              <input type="text" name="competency" id="competency" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full" value="{{ old('competency', $assessment->competency) }}" /> @error('competency') <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white sm:p-6">
              <label for="contexts" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Contexts</label>
              <input type="text" name="contexts" id="contexts" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full" value="{{ old('contexts', $assessment->contexts) }}" /> @error('contexts') <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white sm:p-6">
              <label for="artifact" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Artifact</label>
              <input type="text" name="artifact" id="artifact" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full" value="{{ old('artifact', $assessment->artifact) }}" /> @error('artifact') <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white sm:p-6">
              <label for="link" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Link</label>
              <input type="text" name="link" id="link" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full" value="{{ old('link', $assessment->link) }}" /> @error('link') <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white sm:p-6">
              <label for="notes" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Notes</label>
              <input type="text" name="notes" id="notes" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full" value="{{ old('notes', $assessment->notes) }}" /> @error('notes') <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white sm:p-6">
              <x-jet-label for="rating"> Rating <div class="flex items-center form-check-inline justify-center">
                  <div class="ml-2"></div>
                  <x-jet-checkbox name="rating[]" id="1" value="1" />
                  <div class="ml-2"></div>
                  <x-jet-checkbox name="rating[]" id="2" value="2" />
                  <div class="ml-2"></div>
                  <x-jet-checkbox name="rating[]" id="3" value="3" />
                  <div class="ml-2"></div>
                  <x-jet-checkbox name="rating[]" id="4" value="4" />
                  <div class="ml-2"></div>
                  <x-jet-checkbox name="rating[]" id="5" value="5" />
                  <div class="ml-2"></div>
                  <x-jet-checkbox name="rating[]" id="6" value="6" />
                  <div class="ml-2"></div>
                  <x-jet-checkbox name="rating[]" id="7" value="7" />
                  <div class="ml-2"></div>
                  <x-jet-checkbox name="rating[]" id="8" value="8" />
                  <div class="ml-2"></div>
                </div>
              </x-jet-label> @error('rating') <div class="items-center justify-center">
                <p class="text-justify text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
              </div> @enderror
            </div> @error('rating') <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
          </div>
          <div class="flex items-center justify-end px-4 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-right sm:px-6">
            <button class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 border border-transparent rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-gray-700 active:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-900 focus:shadow-outline-gray disabled:opacity-25 transition ease-in-out duration-150"> Edit </button>
          </div>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>undefined
</x-app-layout>
```

**Assessments Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreAssessmentRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateAssessmentRequest;

use App\Models\Assessment;

class AssessmentsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $assessment = Assessment::all();
        
        return view('assessments.index', compact('assessment'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('assessments.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(StoreAssessmentRequest $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validated();
        $data['rating'] = implode(", ",$data['rating']);
        Assessment::create($data);
        
        //Assessment::create($request->validated());
        
        return redirect()->route('assessments.index');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Assessment $assessment)
    {
        return view('assessments.show', compact('assessment'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Assessment $assessment)
     
    
    {    
  

         return view('assessments.edit', compact('assessment'));
         
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(UpdateAssessmentRequest $request, Assessment $assessment)
    {
        
        $data = $request->validated();
        $data['rating'] = implode(", ",$data['rating']);
        $assessment->update($data);
        return redirect()->route('assessments.index');

    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Assessment $assessment)
    {
        $assessment->delete();
        return redirect()->route('assessments.index');

    }
}
```

**UpdateAssessmentRequest**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UpdateAssessmentRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
        'type' => 'required',
        'learner' => 'required',
        'assessor' => 'required',
        'competency' => 'required',
        'contexts' => 'required',
        'artifact' => 'required',
        'inquiry' => 'required',
        'link' => 'required',
        'notes' => 'required',
        'rating' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: @inquisitivewaffle can you clarify this please: "When I try to edit in a submission all of the text based data shows up but the checkboxes will not re-populate.".

Comment: Hey @user883992158,

Thanks for the reply! 

What I mean is that I have two blades, one is for making initial submissions and one for making edits to submissions.

When I submit the form, everything goes to the database, but when I attempt to edit a submission the checkboxes are blank. 

[Check out this link](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1MgfQyyrsFDU9-buXmzXxeiuKSZ7bxEFo6qZkYRN7M6w/edit?usp=sharing) to see what I am talking about.

Comment: looks like you just need to explicitly set the checkboxes to have the "checked" attribute; you can do it like so... `@if($x == $y) checked @endif`; read the docs on blade directives (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#blade-directives)